# Which Ubuntu server install

Tags: server, 64-bit, intel

I am a newb to linux. I want to build a network server/file share. I have an Intel G3258 processor, 4gb ram and want to take advantage of the 64-bit processing abilities. It doesn't look like the latest stable release for Ubuntu server is for an Intel chip. Am I wrong? If not, which previous Ubuntu server release works for the 64-bit Intel chips?

Comment: You just got confused by marketing and trademarks, as we all have at one time :)

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS....   :)

Answer (score 0):

The amd64 is also for intel, the name is used because amd developed the 64 bit extension for x86 architecture. Intel at the tie had an incompatible 64 bit servr chip ia64 itanium which flopped, so intel copied amd 64 extensions for x86.
So you should use ubuntu 14.04.01 64 even if there is an amd in the name.
Have fun.